# LINQ queries possible to use Foreign key to get value from other table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

Is it possible to make a LINQ method query to the table Timeunit below and use the foreign key Employee or Order to get data from certain rows?

This is what I'm trying to achieve. To the View I pass a ViewModel with Timeunit, Employee and Order. And within a ForEach loop of Order in the View, I try to get all employees who have been working with that order. Is this possible or am I thinking wrong here?

```
@foreach (var item1 in Model.orderlist)
{
@Model.timeunitlist.Where(x => x.OrderID == item1.EmployeeID).FirstName ????
}

public class Timeunit
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public int Week { get; set; }
public int HoursPerWeek { get; set; }
public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
public int? OrderID { get; set; } 
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 1: The other two tables

```
public class Order
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int? ManufacturerID { get; set; }
public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Timeunit> Timeunits { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 2: The View Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Timeunit> timeunitList = new List<Timeunit>();
    public List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
    public List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
}
```

What I need is for each Order, I need to list all Timeunits that match each Order a certain week and to show how many hours each Employee has worked in each Order

Comment: `@Model.timeunitlist.Where(x => x.OrderID == item1.EmployeeID).Select(x => x.Employee.FirstName)` might work

Comment: What is your view model. Is property `orderlist` a collection of `Timeunit`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the other two tables if that could be of any help?

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your suggestion, but it seems like it's not working because after ... == item.1.... I don't get any EmployeeID.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I also added the View Model. Was this what you asked for?

Comment: Not clear what you wanting to display. I assume there is a many-many relationship between `Employee` and `Order` defined by the `Timeunit` model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes that is correct it's a many-to-many rellationship between Order and Emplyee. What I want to display is for each Order, I would like to get all Employees that has been involved and how many HoursPerWeek and Name. Not possible the way I'm trying?

Comment: What you need to a `.GroupBy(x => x.OrderID)` clause. But it should be done in the controller, not the view. And its not clear why your view model has properties for the collections of `Employee` and `Order`

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, I understand that I'm on a track that isn't working. I want to learn and feel some progress in my project. Could you be kind and answer a tell a little it more and show how I should use the query in the controller instead? About the View Model, I thought I needed the Employee and Order to be able to reach the data from those tables? Or must I use link/bridge table to be able to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108693/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-3d-kreativ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display your collection of `Timeunit` grouped by `Order` you need to use a linq `.GroupBy()` clause.  Start by creating view models to represent what you want to display in the view

```
public class OrderVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeVM> Employees { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
}
```

and the in the controller, use a linq query to project you data into the view models

```
IEnumerable<OrderVM> model = db.Timeunits
    .Where(x => x.Week == 1)
    .GroupBy(x => x.OrderID)
    .Select(x => new OrderVM()
    {
        Name = x.FirstOrDefault().Order.Name,
        Employees = x.Select(y => new EmployeeVM()
        {
            Name = y.Employee.Name,
            Hours = y.HoursPerWeek
        })
    }).AsEnumerable();
return View(model);
```

and then in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<OrderVM>
@foreach (var order in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => order.Name)
    foreach(var employee in order.Employees)
    {
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => employee.Name)
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => employee.Hours)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a missing ) somewhere in the Controller code. I can't figure out where it should be? I just get red error lines below the code when I try to add it.

Comment: I want to add it just before the last }, but then I get red lines all over the code and a very long error message that ends with Are you missing a cast? Perhaps this could be a clue

Comment: The missing `)` was in the line above `}).AsEnumerable();` (see edit)

Comment: Also refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BOZf96) for a working example

Comment: Hi, again it's working better know, but in the View I get some kind of error about possible missing using directive or an assembly reference. How can I solve this? I guess it's just a miner thing I have missed somewhere!?

Comment: I assume its because of `@model IEnumerable<OrderVM>` - you either need to use the fully qualified name - `IEnumerable<yourAssembly.OrderVM>` or add a `@using yourAssembly` to the view

Comment: I'm trying with @using.namespace but it still won't detect it!? I thought I needed to add properties for the view models in the ApplicationDbContext class, but it didn't help. Any ideas what I could have missed?

Comment: There is nothing to be done regarding `ApplicationDbContext` - they are view models and have nothing to do with EF (and if they did it would all fail). Are your sure you are adding the right namespace? Your view models should be in a separate folder/assembly - say `ViewModels`. Note in the fiddle its `@model IEnumerable<HelloWorldMvcApp.OrderVM>`

Comment: My view models are in the same folder as the other models, the Model folder. Not working?

Comment: You need to move them. View models need to be in a separate folder.

Comment: Ok, I have moved them, but do I need to ReBuild or do something else?

Comment: Possibly? But if you have done any EF migrations that may have to be undone as well

Comment: I have done a EF migration, but what do you mean with "to be undone"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108783/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-3d-kreativ).